# Document #defines including it's value in doxygen

Tags: c, macros, doxygen

I use doxygen to document my "extern C" DLL.

All funtion returns are defined in a seperate file like the following:

```
#define ERROROPENFILE 12345 /**< Description */
```

Now I want to display them correctly in my documentation. But all I get is:

> #define ERROROPENFILE

and the description when I click on it. I have found no possibility to show the value of the define.

My preprocessor settigs are:

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = NO
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? I see the value of the `ERROROPENFILE` in the documentation based on the `#define ERROROPENFILE 12345 /**< Description */` and the mentioned settings.

Comment: 1.8.12 I will check if there is a newer version.

Comment: installed new version. still the same. Could it be I deaktivated some functionality?

Comment: Is possible, but without knowing what you deactivated  it is hard to tell. A full example showing the problem would be best. Did you try just the example with the line and settings you provided?